# How support UWP commandline AND UWP UI at the same time?

Tags: c#, uwp

My current app looks like the following:

```
public static class Program
{
    //Default code-gen unless we include DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_MAIN in the build properties.
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IActivatedEventArgs activatedArgs = AppInstance.GetActivatedEventArgs();
        if(ActivationKind.CommandLineLaunch.Equals(activatedArgs?.Kind))
        {
            CommandLineActivatedEventArgs cmdLineArgs = activatedArgs as CommandLineActivatedEventArgs;
            CommandLineActivationOperation operation = cmdLineArgs.Operation;
            string activationPath = operation.CurrentDirectoryPath;
            System.Console.WriteLine("foo");
        }
        else
        {
            global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Start((p) => new App());
        }

    }
}
```

My manifest:

```
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" desktop4:SupportsMultipleInstances="true">
    <uap5:Extension Category="windows.appExecutionAlias" [...]
```

Depending whether the user started the app from the command prompt or the start menu, the UI will be displayed as shown. But when the user starts the app from cmd, the output of Console.WriteLine("foo") is not shown.

Therefore I added the `desktop4:Subsystem="console"`.This leads to the console windows being started regarless whether the user starded the app the user started the app from the startmneu or the command line.
how can i make sure that the console window will be shown only by starting from the command prompt? Do I have to create a second uwp project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many additional considerations for UWP console apps. Such as only C++ /WinRT and C++ /CX UWP apps may be console apps. And it must target the Desktop or ioT project. 
Form your code I could figure out it is UWP application. And even if it was UWP application, you could not launch it in two models **UI** or **Console**. Because, it may not create windows. For more you could refe C[reate a Universal Windows Platform console app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/console-uwp).

Comment: So I would need to ship a uwp ui app and a uwp console app in one appx? Is this possible?

Comment: You could not integrate two uwp apps in one appx package.

Comment: So the only way to provide a console and a UI experience would be to publish two windows store apps? Is there no workaround to ship both types of apps ?

Comment: You could add console app's store link into normal uwp app, and tell use install it from store manually.